# Are there cheat codes for Grand Theft Auto San Andreas on the iPhone?

Tags: ios, grand-theft-auto-san-andreas

Is it possible to enter cheat codes on Grand Theft Auto San Andreas for iOS?

I want to buy the game for my iPhone 4, but I'd still like to have the ability to enter cheat codes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, GTA San Andreas does not support cheats on mobile phones except some Android versions.